# Как добавить растяжимое пространство между элементами QGridLayout?

Tags: python, gui, pyqt, qlayout, qgridlayout

Мой код добавляет в контейнер `box` четыре виджета:

- Надпись `label`;
- Три кнопки - `btn1`, `btn2` и `btn3`.

`box` - это `QGridLayout` и мне нужно добавить растяжимое пространство между его строками как указано на изображении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как мне это сделать?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        box = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text')
        box.addWidget(label, 0, 0, 1, 2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button 1')
        box.addWidget(btn1, 1, 0)

        btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button 2')
        box.addWidget(btn2, 1, 1)

        btn3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button 3')
        box.addWidget(btn3, 2, 0, 1, 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `QGridLayout.setVerticalSpacing` https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html#verticalSpacing-prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> QGridLayout::setRowStretch(int row, int stretch)
>
> Устанавливает коэффициент растяжения для строк. Первая строка номер 0.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        box = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        
        box.setRowStretch(0, 1)   
        
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text')
        box.addWidget(label, 1, 0, 1, 2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        box.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        
        btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button 1')
        box.addWidget(btn1, 3, 0)
        btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button 2')
        box.addWidget(btn2, 3, 1)
        
        box.setRowStretch(4, 1)
        
        btn3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button 3')
        box.addWidget(btn3, 5, 0, 1, 2)

        box.setRowStretch(6, 1)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]